# Gradle 8.0.2 - Unable to deploy Omnifaces 'showcase-master'

Tags: gradle, primefaces, omnifaces

Can build & deploy Omnifaces 'showcase-master' from 'https://showcase.omnifaces.org/'

Using:

```
mvn clean package -Pnon-ee,mojarra-4.0.0.SP01
```

Deployed 'showcase-4.1.war' on WildFly 27.0.1 using 'jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java':

```
12:06:00,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-preview-27.0.1.Final/standalone/data/content/2a/616ac15dad5483fcb190a5fd5bee2bda074bf8/content
12:06:00,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "showcase-4.1.war" (runtime-name: "showcase-4.1.war")
12:06:02,305 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment showcase-4.1.war
12:06:02,441 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final
12:06:02,784 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'SomeEJB' in deployment unit 'deployment "showcase-4.1.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/showcase-4.1/SomeEJB!org.omnifaces.showcase.cdi.SomeEJB
    java:app/showcase-4.1/SomeEJB!org.omnifaces.showcase.cdi.SomeEJB
    java:module/SomeEJB!org.omnifaces.showcase.cdi.SomeEJB
    java:global/showcase-4.1/SomeEJB
    java:app/showcase-4.1/SomeEJB
    java:module/SomeEJB

12:06:02,947 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.micrometer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMMTREXT0002: Micrometer Subsystem is processing deployment
12:06:02,968 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYTRACEXT0012: No Jaeger endpoint or sender-binding configured. Installing a no-op sender
12:06:02,981 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-6) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
12:06:02,982 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=showcase-4.1.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=NoopSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=MacBook-Pro-2.local, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=127.0.0.1}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
12:06:03,313 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) WELD-000900: 5.1.0 (Final)
12:06:04,696 INFO  [org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Using OmniFaces version 4.1
12:06:04,947 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketEndpoint for path /omnifaces.push/{channel}
12:06:04,987 INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Initializing Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01 for context ''
12:06:05,922 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) Running on PrimeFaces 12.0.0
12:06:06,013 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 93) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
12:06:06,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "showcase-4.1.war" (runtime-name : "showcase-4.1.war")
```

Displays:

```
https://localhost:8443/components/graphicImage
```

The 'pom.xml' is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>showcase</artifactId>
    <version>4.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Omnifaces Showcase</name>
    <description>Showcase for Faces 4.x utility library</description>
    <url>https://showcase.omnifaces.org</url>
    <organization>
        <name>OmniFaces</name>
        <url>https://omnifaces.org</url>
    </organization>
    <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>balusc</id>
            <name>Bauke Scholtz</name>
            <email>balusc@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>arjan.tijms</id>
            <name>Arjan Tijms</name>
            <email>arjan.tijms@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/omnifaces/showcase.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:omnifaces/showcase.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However trying to build & deploy with 'Gradle' migrating from Maven using 'init' I get:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/")
    }

    maven {
        url = uri("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
    }
}

dependencies {
    api("org.omnifaces:omnifaces:4.1")
    api("org.primefaces:primefaces:12.0.0")
    api("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.4")

    //providedCompile("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")
    compileOnly("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")
}

group = "org.omnifaces"
version = "4.1"
description = "Omnifaces Showcase"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications.create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
        from(components["java"])
    }
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

tasks.withType<Javadoc>() {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

gradle build --info

```
Initialized native services in: /Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/native
Initialized jansi services in: /Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/native
Received JVM installation metadata from '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home': {JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home, JAVA_VERSION=19.0.2, JAVA_VENDOR=Oracle Corporation, RUNTIME_NAME=OpenJDK Runtime Environment, RUNTIME_VERSION=19.0.2+7-44, VM_NAME=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, VM_VERSION=19.0.2+7-44, VM_VENDOR=Oracle Corporation, OS_ARCH=x86_64}
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 2558). The daemon log file: /Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/daemon/8.0.2/daemon-2558.out.log
Starting 54th build in daemon [uptime: 6 hrs 9 mins 38.159 secs, performance: 100%, GC rate: 0.00/s, heap usage: 0% of 512 MiB, non-heap usage: 45% of 384 MiB]
Using 16 worker leases.
Now considering [/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle] as hierarchies to watch
Watching the file system is configured to be enabled if available
File system watching is active
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle/settings.gradle.kts'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle/build.gradle.kts'.
Included projects: [root project 'showcase-master-Gradle']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'showcase-master-Gradle' using build file '/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle/build.gradle.kts'.
The configuration :classpath is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration :classpath is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
The configuration :classpath is both resolvable and consumable. This is considered a legacy configuration and it will eventually only be possible to be one of these.
The configuration :classpath is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
Caching disabled for Kotlin DSL accessors for root project 'showcase-master-Gradle' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping Kotlin DSL accessors for root project 'showcase-master-Gradle' as it is up-to-date.
All projects evaluated.
Task name matched 'build'
Selected primary task 'build' from project :
The configuration :mainSourceElements is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
The configuration :testResultsElementsForTest is both consumable and declarable. This combination is incorrect, only one of these flags should be set.
Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':jar', task ':assemble', task ':compileTestJava', task ':processTestResources', task ':testClasses', task ':test', task ':check', task ':build']
Tasks that were excluded: []
Resolve mutations for :compileJava (Thread[#2704,Execution worker,5,main]) started.
:compileJava (Thread[#2704,Execution worker,5,main]) started.

> Task :compileJava FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':compileJava' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileJava'.
Full recompilation is required because no incremental change information is available. This is usually caused by clean builds or changing compiler arguments.
Compiling with toolchain '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home'.
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/showcase/App.java:78: error: cannot access FacesContext
                primeFacesVersion = new PrimeEnvironment(getContext()).getBuildVersion();
                                    ^
  class file for javax.faces.context.FacesContext not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 665ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

**(2)** Changed:

```
providedCompile("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")"
```

to:

```
compileOnly("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")
```

How error with:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/showcase-master-Gradle/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/showcase/App.java:78: error: cannot access FacesContext
                primeFacesVersion = new PrimeEnvironment(getContext()).getBuildVersion();
                                    ^
  class file for javax.faces.context.FacesContext not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: The error says the class `javax.faces.context.FacesContext` is missing. Are you sure this class is correct? You have a dependency on `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0`, [which contains `FacesContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/context/facescontext), but the package is `jakarta.faces.context`, not `javax.faces.context`.

Comment: Thanks. Changed 'providedCompile("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")' to 'compileOnly("jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api:10.0.0")'. Now "Error: cannot access FacesContext primeFacesVersion = new PrimeEnvironment(getContext()).getBuildVersion();